# Get value from options to javascript in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In view , I have code

```
 <tr>
  <td><%= form.label :category_id %></td>
  <td><%= form.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, 'id', 'name'), :class => 'form-control',:onchange => 'addCategory(category_id)'%></td>
</tr>
```

and script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('select').change(addCategory);
  function addCategory(category_id){
    alert(category_id.value);
 }
</script>
```

I don't know how to get value option selected to use as input function addCategory().

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('select').change(addCategory);
  function addCategory(){
    alert($(this).val());
 }
</script>
```

`$(this)` refers to the new selected element, with `val()` method you get its value

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla approach.

```
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function(e){
  alert(e.target.value);
})
```

or define an `addCategory(e)` function, and pass it as a callback to `change` event.

```
function addCategory(e) {
  alert(e.target.value);
}

document.querySelector('selector').addEventListener('change', addCategory);
```

`e.target` is the same with `$(this)` on Ursus' answer.

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function(e){
  alert(e.target.value);
})
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Opel</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
  <option value="5">Lada</option>
</select>
```